# Is Jesus talking about supererogatory merit in Matt 5:38-48? i.e. earning a reward rather than sin

Tags: exegesis, biblical-basis, new-testament, merit

I know the word "merit" will send up red flags for Protestants, but what I mean has nothing to do with justification.  By supererogatory merit I mean doing something not required, and doing it for the purpose of earning a reward (not of being justified).  The reason I ask the question is because normally I've read Matt 5:38-48 as a set of disjointed verses (reading it in the KJV which is always printed verse-by-verse).  But recently having read it in a few modern translations that arrange the verses in paragraphs, I noticed something interesting.

The verses on turning to the other cheek, giving your coat to anyone who sues for your shirt, loving your enemies, all seem to be connected to verse 46 "For if you love those who love you, what reward do you have?"  So its all about trying to earn a reward.  "And if you greet only your brothers, what more are you doing than others?"  Ah, and its about doing more than others!

This calls in question the traditional interpretation that its a sin to defend yourself, to defend yourself in a lawsuit, to hate your enemy, and presents these things as extras, something above and beyond for those who want to do more than others and earn a special reward.

So my question is basically, what do you think?  Is there any basis to this interpretation or do you think its entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Matt 5:38-48 is a depiction of the type of system you are describing. Rather, it appears to be Jesus doing something he often did, namely, turning the thoughts and traditions of man upside-down. When He says "you have heard it said...", he is referring to some Rabbi's teaching somewhere (that is how they often taught back then, similar to PhD's today quoting one another).

However, there IS a biblical basis to defend the type of system you are curious about. Read 1 Corinthians 3:10-15.

(NIV)
10 By the grace God has given me, I laid a foundation as a wise builder, and someone else is building on it. But each one should build with care. 11 For no one can lay any foundation other than the one already laid, which is Jesus Christ. 12 If anyone builds on this foundation using gold, silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw, 13 their work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each person’s work. 14 If what has been built survives, the builder will receive a reward. 15 If it is burned up, the builder will suffer loss but yet will be saved—even though only as one escaping through the flames.

Paul says here that no one can lay another foundation (the foundation must be Christ), so, the foundation is your salvation or justification by Christ's body and blood (I, as a Protestant, would say "faith alone"). However, Paul also states that each man builds on this foundation using materials (your works and/or fruits, or merits), and that we will receive rewards according to how our works hold up in God's test (most likely on judgment day).

I hope that helped to answer your question.

Comment: I'm Catholic now and I can definitely see how this sort of thinking led me into Catholicism and out of Protestantism. One of the few answers I gave back then that I would still (at least mostly) stand by as a Catholic.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 5;38-48  dipicts  the  golden  rule.

Matthew 7;12  Therefore  all  things  whatsoever  ye  would  that  men  should  do  to  you,  do  ye  even  so  to  them:  for  this  is  the  law  and  the  prophets.

Mark  12;31  And  the second  is  like,  namely  this,  Thou  shalt  love  thy  neighbour  as  thyself.  There  is  none  other  commandment  greater  than  these

The  golden  rule  is  the  principle  of  true  courtesy.  The  truest  illustration  is  seen  in  the  life  of  Jesus  Christ.  Those  that  have  Christ  within  will  reveal  the  same  spirit.  As  children  of  God  we  are  to  impart  the  love  of  Christ,  to  those  in  ignorance,  and  darkness  even  as  we  were  in  their  place,  and  would  desire  them  to  impart  to  us.  Knowing  the  love  of  God,  and  having  received  of  the  rich  gifts  of  His  grace  above  the  most  backward  and  degraded  soul  on  the  earth,  are  you  in  his  debt  to  impart  the  gifts  to  him.

Hebrews 10;34  For  ye  had  compassion  of  me  in  my  bonds,  and  took  joyfully  the  spoiling  of  your  goods,  knowing  in  yourselves  that  ye  have  in  heaven  a  better  and  enduring  substance.